# Trying to get an attachment from a post in a Wordpress loop but getting all, from all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all - this is a question mainly about **the loop**™. I'm also having problems with the attachment thing, but that is somehow secondary since there are snippets around there I think could be useful.

Ok, so this is want I want to do in a front page:

- get 7 posts from custom post type 'portfolio'
- only with the first one, get an specific attachment (in any possible way, be it filename, order in the media manager... whatever is the best, more clean way)
- with the other 6, just get the_post_thumbnail() and little more.

Now, I have this:

```
<?php
$args = array (
'post_type' => 'portfolio',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 7
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$first_post = true; /* we will take the latest work first */
?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php
if ($first_post):
$first_post = false;
?>

    <div> /* This is the div for the first item */
            <?php /* let's take the first attachment */
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'order' => 'DESC'
                );

            $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            if ( $attachments ) :
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) :
                   echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
<?php else: ?>
    /* Do something with the other 6 posts and their post_thumbnail */
<?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And now for the questions:

- First and foremost: if I set 'numberposts' to all (-1) when trying to recover the attachment, I get ALL attachments from ALL 'portfolio' posts. Shouldn't I be interacting only with the current post (the_post())? I can't quite grasp the concept of the loop here, this is the main question.
- That code won't get me the first attachment, even if it's placed in the first place in that post's media manager.

Should I go for secondary or nested loops? I've read and re-read the codex and other tutorials but still can't wrap my head around it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Shakti Patel gave me the key to the answer, but didn't really answer my question about the loop so here it goes:

The problem was with `get_posts`. It actually runs a parallel query to the main one without taking into account the current step of the loop. So we have to ask it for the attachments of the current post, which since we're in the loop is stored within `$post->ID`. So knowing that, we have to request the first attachment for the current post like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
```

That way we specify what is the post from which we'll get the first attachment, and while we're on it, exclude the post thumbnail.

I don't know if this is the best way since we're already on a loop and we shouldn't need a new query, shouldn't we be able to retrieve that attachment without the `get_posts` bit?

Anyway, for more info on `get_posts` (read while not half asleep): http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

used this code :

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
        ) );

        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
                $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                echo $thumbimg;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the second part, the attachment one. What does that block do?

I tried the first part but instead of -1 I set it to 1, and with the extra post_parent and exclude parameters it does exactly what I was after, so thanks for that!

Still, I don't grasp the concept of the loop. Why do I have to use post_parent? Am I not interacting with only the current post in any given loop step?

Comment: Now that I think about this again... could it be that `get_posts()` is getting ALL posts from the main query and ignores the current loop step maybe, that's why `post_parent` is needed?